# Getting validators in classLibrary automatically with .net core 7 FluentValidation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I am doing fluentValidation for my .net core web api project.
I created a few classProjects in my project and made the configuration accordingly.

When there is a "Validations" folder under InventoryManagement.Services, validations do not work.

But when I import the "Validations" folder into "InventoryManagement.API" the validations work fine.

How can I overcome this situation?

So I want "Validations" files to stay in "InventoryManagement.Services".

[InventoryManagement.API, Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zap6E.png)

[Project Overall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgk3W.png)

Automatic validation is done with the following code block, but it only sees when it is in InventoryManagement.API, I want it to see "Validations" under "InventoryManagement.Services" instead

```
builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); instead I just need to point to "InventoryManagement.Services" but how can I point it?

All my Validators have a structure like below

```
    public class CompanyUpdateDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<CompanyUpdateDto>
    {
        public CompanyUpdateDtoValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull().WithMessage("{PropertyName} this field is required").NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} this field is required.");
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("{PropertyName} this field is required.").NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} this field is required.");
            RuleFor(x => x.Description).NotNull().WithMessage("{PropertyName} this field is required").NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} this field is required");
            RuleFor(x => x.BusinessCode).NotNull().WithMessage("{PropertyName} this field is required.").NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} this field is required.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create one dummy interface in the same nanespace as your validators. Then instead of executing assembly, get the assembly that contains that interface.

Comment: Did you inject validators to services also ? like this =>services.AddScoped<IValidator, CompanyUpdateDtoValidator>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fluent team announced that they will remove the method you are using. It could be because of this.https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1963
Can you add like this

```
builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation()
                 .AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters()
                 .AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(Program));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still didn't work, but when I put the validation files in the API project, it works, but I want it to be in the Services project.

Comment: I don't quite understand, but do you want to inject fluentvalidation in service layer?

Comment: Can we inject at the service layer? is there a way

Comment: Look, add a configureservice class to the service layer as in this example. You will create an extension that will have a static class, and the method will be static. Actually, if you don't know, research it. If you have not installed Fluentvalidation in the service layer, download it and then describe it here in the last action you will do. Go inside your API program and type builder.Services.AddApplicationServices()
https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Application/ConfigureServices.cs

Comment: yes I called it this way from within a class and it worked as I wanted. thank you for your help

Comment: Not working for me, I still need to user FromServices and etc...

Comment: There could be many reasons. You can drop the repo and share your code and I'll try to help.